# how to select th with no colspan in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-selectors

I am using this code to get all the tableheads which do not have colspan. It only works in firefox and chrome, but not in IE. What is the equivalent code for IE? thanks.

```
$tableHeaders = $("thead th:not([colspan])", table);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is related to a known bug: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/7234

This is what I come up with, to have a cross-browser workaround:

Compatible IE7,IE8,IE9,FF4,Chrome,Opera11:

```
.filter(":not([colspan]),[colspan='1']")
```

But be carreful, this will also select td/th cells with a colspan attribute setted manually to 1, like ...
[This doesn't append in my code because I remove the colspan attribute if setted to value 1]

So I guess this is what you're looking for:

```
$tableHeaders = $("thead > th", table).filter(":not([colspan]),[colspan='1']");
```

Notice I've added a '>' to the th selector to avoid selecting other th you might have inside (table inside your table header, why not?).

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$tableHeaders = $("#table_id th:not(:has(colspan))");
```

More:

http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/

Comment: As I've understood it :has() doesn't work in that way. As the documentations says: "Selects elements which contain at least one element that matches the specified selector."

So not for attributes, just for child elements.

Comment: no, it didn't work. I tried 
$tableHeaders = $("thead th:not(:has[colspan])", table);
instead and did not work for IE only again.